# Front load washer doesn't power up unless I hit it with hand

Tags: appliances, washer

I've a problem in my fully automatic front load washer that is explained in this video
https://youtu.be/wFKcGBseDgs

As I mentioned in the title of the question, The washer won't power up until I hit it with my hand.

The washer is:
Universal WFT7-22R127-DWH ( May be not popular outside Egypt )

Comment: Loose connection somewhere? Can you post a wiring diagram of the unit?

Comment: The door may have a safety switch to suspend operation in case the door is not shut fully, and it may be malfunctioning. To test try slamming the door to see if that starts it. If that is the problem you might be able to free the switch with a TINY squirt of some silicone oil, but more likely you will have to install a new part.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I still didn't open it, but you think it seems like some wire isn't connected properly ?

Comment: @JimStewart At normal, The washer can be turned on even if the door is open, so it's not a door problem.

Comment: I agree with Jim on the door switch, my older front loader would fail to start If it did not detect that the door was locked but bumping the machine worked until it completely failed and I replaced the switch. +

Answer (score 0):

Use a multimeter and check the wiring going to the control board. Look for loose wires and also examine the solder joints looking for a cold solder. You can also go over the connections with a soldering iron and flow them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case is usually the micro switch sensing when the porthole is closed.
Replacing it should fix the issue.